# Trying to write a query to select posts either written by me, my friends, or posts which my friends like

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I have 3 tables - posts, friendships, and likes -- the important fields described below.

posts: `id, user_id, title`

friendships: `requester_id, accepter_id, is_confirmed`

likes: `post_id, user_id`

I have a method called get_relevant_posts() which should return posts that either I've written, my confirmed friends have written, or my confirmed friends have liked. I've already implemented this in SQLAlchemy, but there's a bug in my query because it only works if the friendships table is not empty (doesnt matter whats in it, just cant be empty). If it is empty, nothing gets returned (improper join?).

This is not a big issue as the friendships table will have something in it 99.99% of the time. But I still want to take a step back and write this in plain SQL -- I just can't seem to wrap my head around it.

**SQLALCHEMY CODE**

```
Friendship1 = aliased(Friendship)
Friendship2 = aliased(Friendship)
Friendship3 = aliased(Friendship)
Friendship4 = aliased(Friendship)
return (DBSession.query(Post)
        .outerjoin(Friendship1, Post.user_id==Friendship1.accepter_id)
        .outerjoin(Friendship2, Post.user_id==Friendship2.requester_id)
        .outerjoin(Like, Post.id==Like.post_id)
        .filter(or_(
            # My post
            self.id==Post.user_id,
            # My friends post, where I'm the requester of the friendship
            and_(self.id==Friendship1.requester_id,
                 Friendship1.is_confirmed==True),
            # My friends post, where I'm the accepter of the friendship
            and_(self.id==Friendship2.accepter_id,
                 Friendship2.is_confirmed==True),
            # Somebodies post, which my friends found interesting
            and_(self.id==Friendship3.requester_id,
                 Friendship3.is_confirmed==True,
                 Like.user_id==Friendship3.accepter_id),
            and_(self.id==Friendship4.accepter_id,
                 Friendship4.is_confirmed==True,
                 Like.user_id==Friendship4.requester_id)))
        .order_by(Post.created_at.desc())
        .limit(limit)
        .offset(offset)
        .all())
```

**PRODUCES THIS**

```
SELECT posts.title AS posts_title
FROM friendships AS friendships_1, friendships AS friendships_2, posts LEFT OUTER JOIN friendships AS friendships_3 ON posts.user_id = friendships_3.accepter_id LEFT OUTER JOIN friendships AS friendships_4 ON posts.user_id = friendships_4.requester_id LEFT OUTER JOIN likes ON posts.id = likes.post_id LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS users_1 ON users_1.id = posts.user_id 
WHERE (posts.user_id = %s OR friendships_3.requester_id = %s AND friendships_3.is_confirmed = %s OR friendships_4.accepter_id = %s AND friendships_4.is_confirmed = %s OR friendships_1.requester_id = %s AND friendships_1.is_confirmed = %s AND likes.user_id = friendships_1.accepter_id OR friendships_2.accepter_id = %s AND friendships_2.is_confirmed = %s AND likes.user_id = friendships_2.requester_id) ORDER BY posts.created_at DESC 
LIMIT %s
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to do an outer join on the friendships table but that you're doing an inner join.

Comment: Show us your code so we can take a look at what is the problem

Comment: @llion I figured that much. As you can see, the code produced is joining from the friendships table for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming we have MS SQL 2005

```
With rels
(
   Select f.requesterId as target_id
   From friendships f 
   Where is_confirmed = 1 and f.accepter_id='Your Id'
   Union 
   Select 'Your id'
)
Select p.*
From posts p 
  left join rel r on r.target_id = p.user_id  -- this will be null on for non-target users
  left join likes l on p.post_id=l.post_id -- here we will pick likes
  left join rel r1 on r1.target_id=l.user_id
where coalesce(r1.target_id, r2.target_id) is not null -- telling sql to pick posts we are interested in
```

or replace CTE rel with sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out in a different way. Doing a subquery with an IN clause to check if any users who like the post are part of my confirmed friends list. The other parts are pretty straigh forward (checking if either I wrote it or a friend wrote it).